# Chronometer в alertdialog

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, можно ли в alertdialog поместить Chronometer? Или может есть какойто другой вариант вызова Chronometer поверх Activity? Подскажите пожалуйста, если есть возможность с примером кода

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что этого нельзя сделать, это обычный `View` и его можно поместить в диалог через метод `setView()` класса `AlertDialog.Builder`/ Если вы пробовали и у вас не получилось, приложите код с попытками и опишите, что не работает, как вы ожидали.

Comment: Я солидарен с @pavlofff, вы сперва попробуйте, проверьте, потом задавайте вопрос, хотя вопрос отпадет...

Comment: @pavlofff можешь подсказать? Сделал все, как описано в ответе  Stanley Wintergreen . Но возникли  проблемы с отображением кнопок внизу(их не видно хотя есть возможность их нажимать) и по истечению времени не воспроизводится звук.

Comment: Если у вас появились новые проблемы, создайте новые вопросы (один вопрос - одна проблема), где подробно опишите проблему, приложите то, что уже сделано, проблемный код и т.п. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать своё кастомное диалоговое окно. Создаём класс. Наследуем его от `DialogFragment`. Дальнейшая реализация по аналогии с `Fragment`. Верстаем `contentView` так чтобы в нём был `Chronometer`. Далее, чтобы показать диалог, создаём экземпляр и вызываем у него метод `show`. То есть ответ на вопрос - да, можно.

Comment: [Лаврик Неизвестный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/258074/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), если вы получили ответ на вопрос, то отметьте его принятым. В противном случае прокомментируйте проблему ещё раз. И обязательно уточните, если вам нужна ещё помощь.